# ClearCase baseline with checkouts

Tags: clearcase

Under the clearcase activity I am working, I have checked in files and checked out files(I am currently working with these checked out files). Can I make a baseline without doing a undo checkout for these checked out files? The reason for asking this is that I want that the baseline to contain only the changes in the checked in files among with other files. That is it should automatically take the previous checked in version of the currently checked out files while making the baseline. Is such a thing possible? I couldn't find any workarounds to this. I cant make a new activity also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [mkbl (make baseline)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm) will only baseline the checked-in files.

```
–vie/w view-tag
```

> Specifies the view from which to create baselines. Baselines are created in the stream that the view is attached to.
>
> For example, if you are working in `coyne_dev_view`, but want to create a baseline from the configuration specified by the view `coyne_integration_view`, use `–view coyne_integration_view`.
>   This option creates a baseline in the project's integration stream that **includes all the checked-in versions** contained in `coyne_integration_view`.
>   If you do not specify view-tag, the current view is used.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks for the answer and fast reply :-)

Comment: @snibu yes, a baseline is made to **freeze* a content. A checked out version is by definition a content which is changing. As such, it cannot be part of a baseline.